# make the tooltip bold in font

Tags: php, html, fonts, tooltip, bold

I am having following code.I want to display tooltip in BOLD.

```
$ToolTip = "test";
   <td class="<?php echo BP_TBL_NUMBER_DATA_CLASS; ?>" Title="<?php echo $ToolTip;?>" ><?php echo $TotalStudentsCount; ?></td>
```

Comment: you should use Jquery tool tip

Answer (score 2):

What you want it not possible with the standard tooltip (title attribute). It is up to browsers to display it any way they want.

You may have to resort to some javascript implementation of a tooltip.

**UDPATE**

Note that with CCS3 you may have a chance of doing it without javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788410/508666

Don't know about browser support for it though. Also it still displays the default title.

Comment: jQuery tooltip comes to mind. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

The other methods describes the way to make the text in the td cell bold, but what he wants is to make the tooltip bold.

Note that the tooltip is a browser depend feature, so i don't think you can't control the font-weight really. You might want to make build your own custom tooltips with some javacript. so you get full control of  the markup.

You might want to try te following though in your external stylesheet

```
td[title] { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Yes, i think you are right, it's browser specific. we cannot change. thank you...